# libgdx - how does the inputprocessor get it's coordinates?

Tags: android, libgdx

In particular, I'm trying to get the touchdown method to first determine if the a touch was on the left or right side of the screen. the screen method defines the width of the screen at 136 pixels I think, but my code seems to interpret about 1/4th of the width of the screen as a left click.

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    touchX=screenX;
    touchY=screenY;
    if(screenX<= 136/2) {
        myToken.onLeftClick();
    }else{
        myToken.onRightClick();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use camera.unproject to get the world coordinates.

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    Vector3 vec=new Vector3(screenX,screenY,0);
    camera.unproject(vec);

    touchX=vec.x;
    touchY=vec.y;
    if(screenX<= 136/2) {
        myToken.onLeftClick();
    }else{
        myToken.onRightClick();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error message for unproject: Non-static method unproject cannot be referenced from a static context. I'm now thinking: should I get the coordinates on game initialization and have the input handler get those coordinates?

Comment: Is your camera static?

Comment: I don't think so, but it is a private OrthographicCamera in a completely different class that I use to render the game. so in that class should I get the screen coordinates in a set of public vars and get the inputhandler to read it?

Comment: I would add a private OrthographicCamera in the class that you have your touchdown method, and add a constructor of that class that takes a camera. public ClassName(OrthographicCamera camera) { this.camera=camera; } Do you understand? Is a easy way to pass your camera to other class